# Compile from command line with Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile

I want to avoid the hassle of creating and building a project in Visual Studio to compile my program. I just want a Makefile, like you do with gcc for example, so that I can compile my program from command line. How can this be done.

Answer (score 1):

Launch the Developer Command Prompt for VS2010 (I have VS2012, so maybe the name is slightly different for you. Mine is on the program menu under "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012->Visual Studio Tools".) This sets up search paths for you and is usually easier than working at the standard cmd.exe prompt.

Write your makefile. The name of the C++ compiler is cl. Use nmake to process your makefile.

If you want assistance on how to create a makefile, please ask that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

just write a MAKEFILE, enter directory with it and type in cmd.exe or IDE command prompt:

```
>nmake
```

([more here](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChToolsMSChain.html)). You can build a program using only compiler without makefile too:

```
>cl /EHsc simple.cpp
```

(use /EHsc to allow C++ exception handling) this will produce executable `simple.exe` ([more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))